# Banno Get User Abilities API Call Failure #2

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Resubmitting question to Banno digital support as my question was deleted. I have an automated process that runs several Banno API calls to unenroll a user from the Zelle Ability. The first time I run the below API call to get the User Abilities in Production I receive a 404 error for every new account.

GET (a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/institutionID/users/userID/abilities)

Five minutes later the process runs again (using the same data, same process) to check for new users, sees the failed user and attempts the same API call which is now successful. I have seen this behavior across 15+ unique member accounts. I am unable to replicate the issue in our test system. Is this a known issue with this specific API call?

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr. I can confirm that these are newly created/enrolled users. This process grabs users from a database that is updated in near real time. It runs every five minutes and if there is a new user, it will unenroll them from Zelle within Banno. I do not have a x-request-id as far as I can see from the logging available with Boomi, the platform running the process. Can you give me a little more info about finding that x-request-id/ response header? Since I cannot replicate the issue when testing, I don't know that I will be able to see the API response.

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr. Here is a date/time from when this occurred: 2023-12-26 04:40:14 PM CST

Comment: Could you share the x-request-id for one of the 404'd requests?

Comment: Could you also elaborate on the sequence of events to replicate - are you seeing this with new users, existing users, existing users with new accounts, etc.? And when you say you've seen it across 15+ unique member accounts, is it always the same user IDs?

Comment: Hi @Sam, I don't believe I can retrieve the x-request-id for you because the system we are using, Boomi, doesn't give us that much detail and I cannot replicate the issue when testing. As for the sequence, these are brand new users (not the same user IDs) who should not have access to Zelle. The data we are checking is updated near real time and the process runs every five minutes so we are trying to unenroll these users very quickly. However, this process has run for many months without any issues before this.

Comment: The x-request-id will be included in the response headers, I would assume you could configure your client to include this in logs. It will significantly help our ability to debug this since it seems unique.

Comment: Hi @Sam, here are my findings now that I've got the x-request-id in the header.  1. Prod Run @ 1/17/24 16:05:09. Error: 404 Not Found and no x-request-id returned.  2. Prod Run 5 minutes later on the same record @ 1/17/24 16:10:15. Success with x-request-id = 072ac66cbeb2e855ff43129d6de586ce.  3. Test Run @ 1/17/24 16:26:59. Error 401 Unauthorized (This is a test specific issue, not related to my post). x-request-id = ca58c9714bcf9f2b0e5c18e10e0cb64c.

Comment: @Sam, have you had a chance to look at the x-request-ids I sent over?

Comment: @Jaime Lopez Jr. Hello, I am looking to get some traction on this issue. I can send more recent x-request-ids if needed.

Comment: I was able to run a test against our Banno Beta site. Here is the x-request-id: b8e93438a3dd246fceee841cf65d78ca. 2024-01-31 10:30:34 AM CST. This was an account created in our test core and logged into so that it populated in Banno Beta. I ran the process a few minutes later and did not encounter the 404 error we are seeing in Prod.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these! I'll pass them to the engineering team to debug and report any findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the logs for one of the requests that you shared (via the x-request-id) the most likely cause for this observation is hitting a race condition with new users.

When a new user is created, the user record needs to be hydrated throughout a series of different systems. Sometimes if a user is new, not all systems will have a record of that user just yet, which is why you will see the user in your list of all users, but will receive a 404 from the `a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionID}/users/{userID}/abilities` (this endpoint may not know of the user just yet).

This would also explain why you see the 404 first, then successfully make the request a few minutes later.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Sam. Are you able to tell me how long on average it takes the a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionID}/users/{userID}/abilities endpoint to update so that I can build that into my process?

Comment: I don't have a specific time to share.